# How to solve IE9 scrolling repaint issue with fixed-position parent that has -ms-transform:translate?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a parent div that has -ms-transform: translateX(50%) translateY(40%); position: fixed;

My inner child div has fixed-height and overflow: auto

In IE9 (only real IE9), this causes weird scrolling issues (it doesnt repaint properly).

Anyone face this, know any fixes or workaround?

Here's code to demonstrate this issue:

```
<div style="-ms-transform: translateX(50%) translateY(40%); position: fixed;">
    <div style="height: 300px; width: 300px; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto;">
        foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Still didn't find any ways around this. For now I'm just avoiding -ms-transform.

Comment: I am having the same issue. did you find a solution about this?

Comment: @scooterlord - no, I ended up removing the -ms-transform.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but hey, this worked for me and could work for anyone else coming here. I replaced my "-ms-transform" with "-ms-filter"

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=1, M12=0, M21=0, M22=1, SizingMethod='auto expand')";
```

Comment: Incredible, this works. Thank you so much you just saved me a huge headache

Answer (score 0):

Try to play with the overflow property - set the overflow property to scroll. I.e, `overflow-y:scroll` and see if that fixes it.