# max-height and overflow not scrolling on ie9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

I have a very strange issue on ie9 where a div with a max-height (set with calc() and vh) and overflow auto is not scrolling.

You can see what is happening by clicking on this image (if the GIF does not load here):

[image]

My HTML:

```
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal__title">Modal Title</div>
  <div class="modal__body">
    <p>When I am too tall, I should scroll on ie9, but I don't.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal__footer">Footer here</div>
</div>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
.modal {
  min-width: 500px;
  max-width: 800px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  max-height: 65vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
  top: 15vh;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.modal__body {
    max-height: calc(65vh - 120px)); // 120 is the combined height of the header and footer
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

I don't understand why this is happening, as ie9 support vh, calc() and max-height.  Any ideas?

JSFiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/sbgg5bja/3/

Comment: There is a typo `max-heigh:` to `max-height:`. Maybe the issue?

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: @sebastianbrosch - sorry, no, that was just my typing here :P

Comment: @CornéSteenbakkers Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sbgg5bja/4/

Comment: *Dear IE, This is why we hate you. — Sincerely, Every Developer Ever.*  This looks like a render issue.  Have you tried this on other Operating Systems (Windows 10, 8, 7)?  Is this running on a native machine or a virtual machine?

Comment: What happens if you temporary remove the transform translate ? .. get the feeling it has to do with that

Comment: Actually, while you're at it, if it still behaves bad, also remove the calc() temporary and let us know if it still won't work.

Comment: @JosephMarikle It's been tested on both a VM and native machine.  I'm using Windows 7, ie9 in a VM.

Comment: @LGSon - yes, indeed, removing the transform translate from the modal seems to fix the problem.  Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Obviously, also, if I remove the transform, I have to find another way of centering the modal, which is possibly problematic as I do not know the modal width (only the max-width)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It appears to be a repaint issue, when combining `position: fixed` and `transform: translate`.

Here is 2 possible fixes:

- Set the overflow property to scroll. I.e, `overflow-y:scroll`
- `-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=1, M12=0, M21=0, M22=1, SizingMethod='auto expand')";`

Src: [How to solve IE9 scrolling repaint issue with fixed-position parent that has -ms-transform:translate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21194873/how-to-solve-ie9-scrolling-repaint-issue-with-fixed-position-parent-that-has-ms)

If neither of these does it, you could drop the `transform: translate` and use for example `display: table` to center it.

Comment: `overflow-y: scroll` is not an option, as I only want to see the scrollbar *if* it is actually needed.  However, the filter works perfectly.  Thank-you :)